Is there a PDF reader that can set base font weight? (with heavier/thicker rendering)
I'm comparing Adobe Reader font rendering to other PDF readers, and I find the former to show heavier/thicker/darker base fonts, which results easier to my bad sight.
Is there any free/open-source PDF reader that has a heavier base font rendering and/or can be customized?
I'm looking for a Windows application, offline, without ads, hopefully with a sleek UI.
